# Where can I find the vector sources of the Xubuntu wallpapers?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background, source

I like the wallpapers that come in [xubuntu-wallpapers](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xubuntu-wallpapers) package, so I'd like to use them as intended. But, while the general graphical idea of them is nice, the implementation is bad: the wide gradients taking on the color values from a limited range suffer from banding. I'd like to fix them by re-rendering from the vector source (SVG or whatever) with dithering enabled. But the package source that I can get via `apt-get source` only contains the banded PNGs (only `xubuntu-logo` is present in SVG format).

Is there any primary—vector—source of these images that could be used for re-rendering? Or were they created in raster form from the beginning?